# Fast growing green ground cover. ID please

Tags: lawn

I think this came from my bird feeder. I like it because it’s growing in bare spots my lawn won’t. It looks nice and is soft on the feet. I’d like to find more to finish the other bare spots. It holds up well under my two dogs big feet[image][image]